# jquery and HTML placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am trying to play with jQuery UI, dialog in particular. First I tried the sample code and it works fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>dialog demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
<script>

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {   
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I am trying to create button and dialog dynamically in the script, so I rewrote the code as:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>dialog demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

// Create button
var open_button = document.createElement("button");
open_button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Open the dialog"));
open_button.setAttribute("id", "opener");

document.body.appendChild(open_button);


// Creating dialog
var my_dialog = document.createElement("div");
my_dialog.setAttribute("title", "Dialog");
my_dialog.setAttribute("id", "dialog");

document.body.appendChild(my_dialog);

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And now it fails with the error "body is null". Why is that?

But even if I create dummmy DOM inside the body:

```
<div id="dummy_div"></div>
```

... and then, inside the script, append both the button and the dialog to it instead of body it still does not work.

```
$("#dummy_div").append(open_button);
$("#dummy_div").append(my_dialog);
```

I am probably missing some HTML basics, I would appreciate any explanation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to create the element before your HTML is rendered.

Use this:

```
 $(function() {
   $("#dummy_div").append(open_button);
   $("#dummy_div").append(my_dialog);

   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
   $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
   });
 });
```

Good luck

**Note**

```
$(function() { ... }); is the same thing as $(document).ready()
```

[Read about document.ready() here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Read that for more information about DOM ready.

Comment: One thing - do you have any errors in your Javascript console? You may be missing some assets, either by way of unfinished loading, or wrong url

Comment: I have some warnings, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is executed immediately when it is encountered in the page.  So in your second case, you are trying to write to the `<body>` element before the browser has created it.  Hence why it is null.

Wrap the script in a `window.load()` or a `$(document).ready()` function and you should have everything working.
This will have the JavaScript wait until the entire DOM has been rendered before trying to do your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code on jsfiddle. It's work

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/795Yp/

If you want to embedded it in web page you should call it in the following function :

```
$(function(){


})
```

so :

```
$(function(){
   // Create button
var open_button = document.createElement("button");
open_button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Open the dialog"));
open_button.setAttribute("id", "opener");

document.body.appendChild(open_button);


// Creating dialog
var my_dialog = document.createElement("div");
my_dialog.setAttribute("title", "Dialog");
my_dialog.setAttribute("id", "dialog");

document.body.appendChild(my_dialog);

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});

})
```